# JQuery - SyntaxError: missing formal parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this to find all registered trademark symbols and tm symbols and wrap them in a sup tag with a class. I looked around since there is a couple people who have already asked the question, but none seem to fix my problem. Here is the code

```
$('body :not(script,sup)').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.replace(/[™®]/g, '<sup class="registermark">$&</sup>');
});
```

The error is happening on the first line

```
$('body :not(script,sup)').contents().filter(function(){
```

Comment: Please indicate a few things. What is the code supposed to do? What is the problem? Sample input/output/expected output. Also consider removing irrelevant `wordpress` tag. I'd recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please be descriptive

Comment: On which line is the error ocurring?

Comment: I don't think anything in the code you posted is causing the problem.

Comment: @CassidyWilliams its on the first line

Comment: It's *possible* that there's an invisible character in the `()` of one of your `function()` expressions.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a stack snippet or jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: When I cut and paste that first jQuery expression into the browser console, it works just fine. How sure are you that this code corresponds to the error?

Comment: Try using the `not()` selector method instead, maybe that will help, or at least help debug? https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: @Pointy yea that was the problem on most of the people I found that had the same problem but I cant find why it here.

Comment: @j08691 https://jsfiddle.net/p98ojL02/

Comment: Googling that error message shows that it's always associated with having something incorrect inside the parenthese in `function() {...}`. Check your original code carefully, because there's nothing wrong with the code you posted or the fiddle.

Comment: Isn't it working in the fiddle?